# Trellis chart x categories values are not displaying correctly in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am working on the Trellis chart highchart.
and I have categories values with long names,for that categories value should start from first letter but its showing from the middle of the
categories value to last,

**actual title**: Appleswwwwwwwwwwwe

**now its showing like**: wwwwwwwwe

**But i need to show the title with ellipsis like**

Appleswee...

```
 xAxis: {
          categories: ['Appleswwwwwwwwwwwe', 'Pewerttttttttttttars', 'Oranges', 'Bananas'],
            labels: {
                enabled: i === 0
            }
        },
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hrkdunt8/)

can anyone help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working, I used below code from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6zsn/406/)

```
    label : {
         formatter: function () {
                            var text = this.value,
                                formatted = text.length > 25 ? text.substring(0, 25) + '...': text;
                            return formatted ;
                  } 
            }
```